# How to obtain Evri (Hermes) API credentials

Tags: rest, shipping-method, logistics

After trying to contact Evri for days, I'm seeking help on how to obtain tracking API credentials.

Note: I would stay away from Evri if I could, but a user ships all of their orders through this carrier. I found their [API reference](https://api.business.evri.com/.p2g/index.html), but am unable to use it.

**What I've Tried**

1. Creating an [Evri account](https://www.evri.com/our-services/login) and contacting the emails listed on
   [this ShipEngine guide](https://www.shipengine.com/docs/carriers/evri-guide/) for obtaining API credentials.
2. Requesting an Evri [business account](https://www.evri.com/business-accounts).
3. Calling Evri. I was only able to leave a voicemail. None of the usual tricks worked to talk to a human.
4. Tracking through EasyPost's and Shippo's third-party tracking API, but both require you to have your own Evri API credentials (which kind of ruins the point of a unified API).

What else can I try? Have any developers successfully requested API credentials from Evri or Hermes?

Comment: This is nothing to do with a programming problem, it's something you need to work out with the service provider, not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I received a response from Evri support.

To gain API access you need to ship over 150 parcels per week.
Once you meet this requirement, then contact IT.Integration@hermes-europe.co.uk with your Evri account name
and Evri account ID.
Then Evri should reply with an Auth ID, API key, and API secret so you can start making API calls.

If you don't meet the shipping volume for API access, then the next solution is using the user's account for API access to track their shipments.